# Python: Fail to produce diamond since unable to add space in the first line

Tags: python, for-loop

I'd like to produce a diamond with python, but failed because python cannot allow spaces in the starting positions in the first line. Need your help for advice. My code:

```
space = " "

n = int(input('Enter the number of upper-half column of diamond : '))

for i in range (n):
    print(space * (n-i-1) + "a" * (2+2*i))
for i in range (n):
    print(space * i + "a" * (2*n-2*i))
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of upper-half column of diamond: 4
aa 
  aaaa
 aaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
 aaaaaa
  aaaa
   aa
```

May I know how to fix it? And, are there any better way to write code, such as combining two for-loops into one?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not reproducible. Shape looks as expected after direct copy paste of your code.

Comment: maybe there is problem in compiler. But is there better way to produce the shape?

Answer (score -1):

Try printing a single blank line before printing your diamond.